# Macro not triggered by option button change

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have 3 option buttons linked to cell A1,

I also have a macro that is triggered when Cell A1 is changed.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1")) Is Nothing Then
       Select Case Range("A1").Value
           Case 1
               Range("C7:K32").NumberFormat = "_-* #,##0_-;-* #,##0_-;_-* ""-""??_-;_-@_-"
           Case Else
               Range("C7:K32").NumberFormat = "_-$* #,##0_-;-$* #,##0_-;_-$* ""-""??_-;_-@_-"
        End Select
    End If

End Sub
```

If i manually enter a value into A1 the macro works fine, however if I change the value in `A1` using the option buttons, the macro does not run.

Is there a way to get the macro to run when changing A1s value with the option buttons ?

Comment: If you put `Range("A1") = 1` inside a `Private Sub OptionButton1_Click()` then it should trigger the `Worksheet_Change`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using ActiveX Option buttons then you can assign code to each one.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1")) Is Nothing Then
       Select Case Range("A1").Value
           Case 1
               Range("C7:K32").NumberFormat = "_-* #,##0_-;-* #,##0_-;_-* ""-""??_-;_-@_-"
           Case Else
               Range("C7:K32").NumberFormat = "_-$* #,##0_-;-$* #,##0_-;_-$* ""-""??_-;_-@_-"
        End Select
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub OptionButton1_Click()
    Range("A1") = 1
End Sub

Private Sub OptionButton2_Click()
    Range("A1") = 2
End Sub
```

[image]